# Change date based on time using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with attendance report, each user has an "interval" element.
The problem here is that when the staff sign out the next day the date is always set as the In date even for the Out element (example the second  element):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<transferStaffAttendance version='0.2'>
    <user>100994</user>
       <intervalStart>2020-03-02</intervalStart>
       <intervalEnd>2020-03-02</intervalEnd>
    <entries>
    <entry>
    <entryStart>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>06:37</time>
    </entryStart>
    <entryEnd>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>15:34</time>
    </entryEnd>
    </entry>
    </entries>
</interval>
<interval>
    <user>101400</user>
       <intervalStart>2020-03-02</intervalStart>
       <intervalEnd>2020-03-02</intervalEnd>
    <entries>
    <entry>
    <entryStart>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>00:00</time>
    </entryStart>
    <entryEnd>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>00:00</time>
    </entryEnd>
    </entry>
    </entries>
</interval>
<interval>
    <user>102806</user>
       <intervalStart>2020-03-02</intervalStart>
       <intervalEnd>2020-03-02</intervalEnd>
    <entries>
    <entry>
    <entryStart>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>18:47</time>
    </entryStart>
    <entryEnd>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>03:10</time>
    </entryEnd>
    </entry>
    </entries>
</interval>
</transferStaffAttendance>
```

I want to change the date to the next date if the user sign out after midnight by calculating the difference between In and Out  value like following:

```
<interval>
    <user>102806</user>
       <intervalStart>2020-03-02</intervalStart>
       <intervalEnd>2020-03-03</intervalEnd>
    <entries>
    <entry>
    <entryStart>
         <date>2020-03-02</date>
         <time>18:47</time>
    </entryStart>
    <entryEnd>
         <date>2020-03-03</date>
         <time>03:10</time>
    </entryEnd>
    </entry>
    </entries>
</interval>
```

How can I do this using XSLT?

Comment: Well, compare the values, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 and 3 you can do date arithmetics using the operator `+` and an `xs:date` and a duration as the operands:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="interval[entries/entry/entryEnd/time &lt; entries/entry/entryStart/time]/intervalEnd
                       |
                       interval/entries[entry/entryEnd/time &lt; entry/entryStart/time]/entry/entryEnd/date">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(.) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm new to XSLT and I'm expecting a full workable code, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is here to answer your technical questions, not to provide free training (let alone free coding). Start by reading a book or two.

Comment: @AmmarAli,  Speaking about "free training", all Pluralsight courses, including the ones on XSLT and XPath are **free** for the whole month of April, 2021

Comment: appreciate you help guys, I will definitely do some reading and learning, but I'm stuck on this one and needed a quick fix, again thank you very much.